# Apache Camel multithread processing

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, routes

I want the route to operate in several thread simultainously.

```
from(¨timer://foo¨).to(¨jdbc://myDataSource¨).to(¨mock:results¨)
```

I can use two routes (timer + seda) to get that kind of result, but this is ugly (besides using additional thread), or I can create the route several times. Is there any *normal* way to get that kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the *concurrentConsumers* or *thread* option. See [Competing Consumers EIP](http://camel.apache.org/competing-consumers.html) and [SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) pages where these options described are. Hope it helps!